# How to make call for iphone application?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating an iphone application in which I want the same facility as user taps on the call button and make a phone call to that person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the number you can try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://01234567"]];
```